# how do you subset R data frame based on provided column names via a function argument?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a R function based on given data frame as the first argument, subset the data frame based on provided arguments:

For example, my df is like this:

```
Date       Server1 Server2 Server3 Server4
1/1/2004     10     20       10      5
2/1/2014      4     4        4       20
3/2/2014      1     5        5       39
```

I need to subset this df:

For example, if I pass to this function(x, Server1, Server3, Server4), it will look like this:

```
data<-function(x, ...) {

subset(x, select=c("Server1","Server3", "Server4"))
}
```

But, I the argument list should not be known. It should apply to all data frames not knowing the column names.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass your arguments as strings it should would work fine like this:

```
subset2<-function(x, ...) {
  cols <- c(...)
  subset(x, select=cols)
}

subset2(dat, "Server1", "Server3", "Server4")
```

But I'm not sure why such a wrapper is necessary.  Perhaps I am missing what your true goal is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reconsider whether a wrapper function around `subset` is really necessary. As far as I can see, your intended function does the same as `subset` itself and requires the same arguments with slightly different sintax.

In any case, if you don't know the column names, you can use column indices instead (e.g. `subset(x, select=c(1,3,4)`).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of subset, as on its help page it says specifically in a warning that it's intended for interactive use only. I don't see the problem here, you can simply do the following:

```
data<-function(x, select, ...) {
    tmp <- x[select]
    # do some stuff with it
    return(tmp)
}
```

A simple illustration:

```
data(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Species"))
#     Sepal.Width    Species
# 1           3.5     setosa
# 2           3.0     setosa
```